# Order By with Ruby and MongoID doesn't sort

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I'm unable to get order_by working with mongoId except with `:created_at`.
This works perfectly:

```
Product.order_by(amount_money: :asc).limit(100)
```

But as soon as I change the field to anything else, it doesn't work. So, I'm looking for a way to sort the data before bringing it.

Comment: Did you try `Product.asc(...)` and `Product.desc(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. the reason was that MongoID store BigDecimal values as a string in the MongoDB collections. and sorting strings are hideous.

```
irb(main):001:0> ["1" , "200", "8", "12"].sort
=> ["1", "12", "200", "8"]
```

you can change that into float will solve it, but float isn't correct data format to handle currency. so have a separate float field for sorting purposes, until MongoID comes up with a fix.